# How to attach Link using External Learning Tool in Brightspace LMS Dropbox Create Folder API?

Tags: variable-assignment, dropbox, lms, external-tools

We are using **Dropbox folder API** to create Assignments as mentioned in API documentation (https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html)

We want to add third party Links **(LinkAttachments)** using **external learning tool** through REST **API**. As per API documentation there is no field for Link Attachments in **Dropbox.DropboxFolderUpdateData**.

[DropboxFolderUpdateData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtyNI.png)

We are able to create App tool and links with custom parameter using REST API(s) but unable to use that links in Assignments (Dropbox folder) through API. In this case teacher need to visit the Brightspace interface to add **(LinkAttachments)**.

So, we required the solution to add third party links in Brightspace Assignments (dropbox folders)

The expectation is to create an App using Brightspace API which provide the interface to create assignments with our education materials and links without using Brightspace interface.